# TextView moved down when new line

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I'm currently working on a server-client android application, and in one of my views I have a HorizontalScrollView that contains a vertical LinearLayout. This LinearLayout will contain a bunch of TextViews that are customized with a background. It works fine until the TextViews get a new row because of the character length, it looks like this:

http://puu.sh/9L127/bf29a86639.jpg

The idea is that the text is supposed to fit in the background, is there any way that I can keep the TextView position like the other ones, even though it has multiple rows?

I hope I made myself clear enough, this is how the TextViews are set up in the code:

```
public void setupCard(GameCard card) {
    final int CARD_WIDTH = 200;
    final int CARD_HEIGHT = 100;

    m_card = card;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);
    super.setText(m_card.getContent());
    super.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cardbg);
    super.setLayoutParams(lp);
    super.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

And this is how the activity is set up:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/bng"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the LinearLayout alignes the text baselines of the TextViews.

Try to specify

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

for the LinearLayout.